# Empathy not able to sign into a SIP Account

Tags: empathy, voip, sip

I am running a Ubuntu 10.04 and trying to configure three SIP accounts on my machine. Following is the status of 3 accounts

1. iptel.org - I can sign in - it shows I am online, but I am unable to make calls or receive calls
2. Corporate IP PBX1 (10.30.5.61) - Unable to sign in - Says network error. I am able to connect to this IP PBX using jitsi and same credentials.
3. Corporate IP PBX2 (10.1.3.26) - Able to sign in - Can make incoming & outgoing calls using empathy and jitsi. Works nicely - Audio, Video - both

IP PBX1 - is based on Trixbox

IP PBX2 - is based on PIAF

Would appreciate any help

Comment: Did you find an answer to this problem or are you still looking for help? If you did find a solution please consider adding it here, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Most everything is fixed in 12.04 recommend upgrading.

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type in `update-manager -d` into the command box. Update Manager should open up and tell you:

> New distribution release ’12.04 LTS‘ is available

Comment: 12.04 is still in beta at the moment. So *before* you upgrade please make sure that the upgrade won't affect other software and leave it in an unusable state.

Comment: @qbi that is correct, but the final release is around the corner